# Attributed quote to Nikola Tesla

Tags: reference-request, quote, debunking, tesla

In many serious engineering and scientific publications including IEEE publications, we see a quote attributed to Nikola Tesla which goes like this

> If you want to find the secrets of the universe, think in terms of energy, frequency, and vibration.

However no one gives a reference because this is common quote on social media type posts but no book or publication before the internet era (1990s) ever mentions it. I searched Google Scholar and Google Books with year limited to pre-1999, there is nothing. Is there an authentic reference of this quote? Wiki Quotes also has a reference to a vague website. See for example: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla#Disputed

Comment: The only source for this attribution appears to be an Arizonan by the name of Ralph Bergstresser, (*possibly* [this man](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/212463789/ralph-edgar-bergstresser)) who was supposedly a friend of Tesla, and it is claimed that Tesla said this in a conversation with him in 1942. From what I gather, Mr. Bergstresser was peddling a product supposedly inspired by Tesla's work. The attribution of the quote to Tesla seems extremely questionable to me, but it is hard to prove a negative.

Comment: It is sad people are blindly quoting it in decent journals without any reference. The journals will serve as our historical archives after 50-100 years and this will be taken truth.

Comment: I agree that biographical anecdotes and quotations relating to historical figure that appear to be made upon closer inspection are a vexing yet common phenomenon. Did Marie Antoinette really say (the French equivalent of) "Let them eat cake"? Best as anyone has been able to establish, no.

Comment: Very true...the messages are good but the attributions are hard to trace. Most of the older and new ones are bogus.

Comment: "Everyone can take a random quote on the internet and attribute it to a famous person." -- Abraham Lincoln